# Excel force date to NOT change

Tags: excel, function, date, if-statement, vba

The spreadsheet I am working on involves well over 100 cells, each with (possibly unique) dates, however for simplicity we will say that I have just 2 cells to work with, A1 and B1.
In A1 I want to enter data (could be text, or a number) ONE time...let's say on Monday.
I want to use something like an "IF" statement in B1:
 (If A1 > "" then B1 = date (of data entry)
I want this date to be static (non-changing); in other words, I don't want that date to update on next Friday when I open the file to work in it again.
"Now" always updates. "Today" always updates. I do not want the date to keep changing to the current date, and I don't want to enter a date in the associated cell every time I enter data.
I'm really not sure this is possible using the standard Excel functions, but maybe someone else has an idea...? I've considered using VBA, but I'm not sure that's the best way to go either. TIA!

Comment: The `Date` and `Now` function will automatically update every time the workbook refreshes. If you do not want the cell to change the date ever then simply convert the cell to text using copy pastespecial values.

Comment: So you only want to enter a date the first time A1 changes and never again? Something like =IF(AND(IsEmpty(B1), NOT IsEmpty(A1), Now, B1). Not tested!

Comment: Matt, yes that is correct. Working on your solution now...

Comment: Matt, isn't NOW going to update the current  date every time the worksheet formulas are calculated when the spreadsheet is activated?

Comment: Siddharth, wouldn't that involve me performing that task (convert the cell to text using copy pastespecial values) every time I open the workbook and make changes to the other cells?

Comment: IMHO, you don't need to do so if your original data is nicely tab delimited. paste special is good way to verify the date type we paste. If the source is an excel file too, you would not have to use paste special.

Answer (score 1):

From Google:

Insert a static date or time into an Excel cell:

On a worksheet, select the cell into which you want to insert the current date or time.

Do one of the following: To insert the current date, press Ctrl+; (semi-colon). To insert the current time, press Ctrl+Shift+; (semi-colon).

Comment: The reference I found = this [link](http://www.zeigen.com/shortcuts/2007/03/22/notepad-timestamp/#comment-80). | the best non-vba excel solution known to me. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_  Thanks!